# How to pass a docker image name to my GitHub action

Tags: docker, github-actions

I'm trying to make my first action to build packages inside a given docker container. I have the following `action.yaml` file:

```yaml
name: Build Package
description: Build Debian packages using Docker image

inputs:

  docker_image:
    description: Name of the docker image to use
    required: true

runs:
  using: 'composite'

  steps:
    - name: Check out the repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Build `*.deb` packages
      uses: 'docker://${{inputs.docker_image}}'
      with:
        entrypoint: ./build.sh
```

In the other repository I'm trying to use it:

```yaml
...
    steps:
      - uses: CMakeify-me/build-package-action@v1-beta
        with:
            docker_image: 'cmakeifyme/debian-9-deb-build:1.3'
```

Unfortunately, I've got the error:

```
Error: CMakeify-me/build-package-action/v1-beta/action.yaml (Line: 19, Col: 13):
Error: CMakeify-me/build-package-action/v1-beta/action.yaml (Line: 19, Col: 13): Unrecognized named-value: 'inputs'. Located at position 1 within expression: inputs.docker_image
Error: GitHub.DistributedTask.ObjectTemplating.TemplateValidationException: The template is not valid. CMakeify-me/build-package-action/v1-beta/action.yaml (Line: 19, Col: 13): Unrecognized named-value: 'inputs'. Located at position 1 within expression: inputs.docker_image
   at GitHub.DistributedTask.ObjectTemplating.TemplateValidationErrors.Check()
   at GitHub.Runner.Worker.ActionManifestManager.ConvertRuns(IExecutionContext executionContext, TemplateContext templateContext, TemplateToken inputsToken, String fileRelativePath, MappingToken outputs)
   at GitHub.Runner.Worker.ActionManifestManager.Load(IExecutionContext executionContext, String manifestFile)
Error: Fail to load CMakeify-me/build-package-action/v1-beta/action.yaml
```

Trying just print the `inputs` works fine:

```yaml
    - name: Spam
      run: echo '${{ inputs.docker_image }}'
      shell: bash
```

Meaning, that there is some problem when `inputs.docker_image` is used within the value of `uses:` ;-(

How can I pass the docker image name to be used in my action?

Thank you.

Comment: The second repo doesn't have `inputs.docker_image` defined, right? That might be why it's failing?

Comment: The second repo tries to use the action and provides `with.docker_image` -- if I understand correctly this is the way to pass parameters to the action...

Comment: Yes, you’re correct.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can't use an input/variable with `uses` like that.

This is not explicitly mentioned in the documentation but you can see a warning here: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions

- *Warning: When creating workflows and actions, you should always consider whether your code might execute untrusted input from possible attackers.*

If you need to dynamically pick your docker container, you might have to look into an alternative. You can avoid `uses` and run docker from shell directly, like this...

Call your action, and pass the input via `with`:

```
      - uses: CMakeify-me/build-package-action@v1-beta
        with:
            docker_image: 'cmakeifyme/debian-9-deb-build:1.3'
```

Then your action can us the input via `run`, using `shell` to call docker:

```
    - name: run docker with dynamic image name
      run: 'docker run ${{ inputs.docker_image }}'
      shell: bash
```

Comment: Yeah, I've thought about this way... but it looks like I have to perform `docker pull` before "manually" as well (and maybe `docker login`)... and it makes me sad %( -- what good in the docker support in GH actions if I have to perform all commands "manually" %(

Comment: I don’t think you have any other choice.